# Using onClick event in React map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to loop over nested object in using map on List Component from MUI. When performing click all elements are getting clicked.

This is my class component:

```
class TablePivot extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            pivotData: [],
            firstLevelOpen: false,
            secondLevelOpen: false,
            thirdLevelOpen: false,
        }
    handleFirstListClick = () =>{
        this.setState({firstLevelOpen:!this.firstLevelOpen})
        console.log(this.secondLevelOpen)
    }

    handleSecondListClick = () =>{
        this.setState({secondLevelOpen:!this.secondLevelOpen})
        console.log(this.secondLevelOpen)
    }
    
    handleThirdListClick = () =>{
        this.setState({thirdLevelOpen:!this.thirdLevelOpen})
        console.log(this.thirdLevelOpen)
    }

    render () {
        
        return (
            <>
                
                <List>
                    {Object.entries(this.state.pivotData).map((key, val) =>{
                        // console.log(key[1])
                        return (
                        <ListItemButton onClick = {event => this.handleFirstListClick}>
                            <ListItemText primary={key[0]} />
                            {this.state.firstLevelOpen ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
                            {Object.entries(key[1]).map((key,index) =>{
                                return (
                                    <Collapse in={this.state.firstLevelOpen} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
                                        <List component="div" disablePadding>
                                        <ListItemButton onClick = {this.handleSecondListClick} sx={{ pl: 4 }}>
                                            <ListItemText primary={key[0]} />
                                            {this.state.secondLevelOpen ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
                                            {Object.entries(key[1]).map((key,index) =>{
                                                    <Collapse in={this.state.secondLevelOpen} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
                                                        <List component="div" disablePadding>
                                                        <ListItemButton onClick = {this.handleThirdListClick} sx={{ pl: 4 }}>
                                                            <ListItemText primary={key[1]} />
                                                            {this.state.thirdLevelOpen ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
                                                            {/* {
                                                                Object.entries(key[1]).map((key,index) =>{
                                                                    return (console.log[key])
                                                                })
                                                            } */}
                                                        </ListItemButton>
                                                        </List>
                                                    </Collapse>
                                                })
                                            }
                                        </ListItemButton>
                                        </List>
                                    </Collapse>
                                    
                                )
                            })}
                        </ListItemButton>
                    )
                    
                    
                    })}
                </List>

                
                
                <Snackbar anchorOrigin={{ vertical : "top", horizontal : "right" }} open={this.state.alert} autoHideDuration={5000} onClose={() => this.setState({alert : false})}>
                    <Alert variant="filled" elevation={6} onClose={() => this.setState({alert : false})} severity={this.state.severity}>
                        {this.state.alertMsg}
                    </Alert>
                </Snackbar>
            </>
        )
    }
```

I have tried passing index and event inside onclick like this:

```
handleFirstListClick(event, index) {
        console.log(event.target)

        this.setState(
            prevState => ({
                ...prevState.firstLevelOpen,
                [index]: !prevState.firstLevelOpen
            })
        )

        console.log(this.state.firstLevelOpen)


        // if (this.state.firstLevel === true)
        //     firstLevel[index] = false
        // else
        //     firstLevel[index] = true

        // this.setState({firstLevelOpen:firstLevel});

    }

// Changes inside render() inside list component for passing value
<ListItemButton onClick = {event => this.handleFirstListClick(event, val)}>
```

But doing this will not update state properly. I am not understanding what is going wrong. I am learning react using project. I am struggling for this click event a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click the first `ListItemButton`, it set the `firstLevelOpen` state to `true`.

And at this part of the code
`{this.state.firstLevelOpen ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}`
because the `firstLevelOpen` is now `true`, all the first level `ExpandLess` component will be visible.

To handle the state for each button in the list, you can change the state from boolean into object. What you already did is very similar to the code below.

```
this.state = {
    pivotData: [],
    firstLevelOpen: {},
    secondLevelOpen: {},
    thirdLevelOpen: {},
}
```

on the click handler

```
handleFirstListClick(event, index) {
    this.setState(
        prevState => ({
            firstLevelOpen: {
                ...prevState.firstLevelOpen,
                [index]: !prevState.firstLevelOpen[index]
            }
        })
    )
}
```

and now change the conditional rendering to

```
{this.state.firstLevelOpen[index] ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
```

I haven't test it yet, but I guess it should work.

Comment: It somewhat fixes the issue but now default value is no longer false so it loads with list expanded.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the expand component part. I already added it to the answer.